# rsyslog and netsnmp support for Linux namespaces

Tags: ubuntu, rsyslog, snmp, network-namespaces

I have configured different net *namespaces* (`netns`) on my linux machine (Ubuntu) with different routes in each.
Now, if I want `rsyslog` and SNMP traps (`netsnmp`) to use one of the route from these namespaces - would that work?
I tried searching but could not find any specific config which referred to any namespace support.
Any help, or pointers to docs, very much appreciated.